# Facebook Application refresh when I swipe down on the screen

Tags: android, facebook

I have a facebook application running in my facebook app on my Android phone.

When I swipe down the screen with my finger, the application make a refresh of the "page" app; and then I get a message saying "Page not found"..

Someone already got this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I am getting a lot of weird staff with HTC sense... But this one I haven't try yet.

Comment: but there is something that can disable the swipe move? Or is something stucked in Android?

Comment: Than it is another story, did you tried to implement OnTouchListener , and don't nothing when there is swap ... or something like that .